# Vertically and Horizontally Align div within div with :after selector

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have this HTML & CSS code :

```css
html {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.triangle-down {
  width: 90%;
  height: auto;
  padding-left: 50%;
  padding-top: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.triangle-down:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  margin-left: -500px;
  margin-top: -500px;
  border-left: 500px solid transparent;
  border-right: 500px solid transparent;
  border-top: 500px solid #9CE08F;
}
div {
  float: left;
  margin: 0.5%;
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle-down">
  <div>&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

And I am trying to make the `div` within the `triangle-down` to align vertically and horizontally. Alternatively, I can just use text instead of div and align it. In this case I am using the :after selector and I cannot change the CSS in a way to make it work. I know how to do it using `position:relative` and `position:absolute` or even the `display:inline-block`.

But in this case, it is more complex. If I change the CSS for triangle-down, then I am not getting a triangle anymore.

I want to have something like this :

[image]

Comment: Don't get a complete understanding of your question, can you provide a image as example or something?

Comment: @Apolo Radomer now check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.btn {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 0px; width:100%;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    background: gray;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-bottom:42%;
    background-clip:content-box;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.btn:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top:0px; left: 0;
    background-color:inherit;
    padding-bottom:50%; width:57.7%;
    z-index:-1;
    
    -webkit-transform-origin:0 0;
    -ms-transform-origin:0 0;
    transform-origin:0 0;
    
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-30deg) skewX(30deg);;
    -ms-transform: rotate(-30deg) skewX(30deg);
    transform: rotate(-30deg) skewX(30deg);
}
/** FOR THE DEMO
body{background: url('http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-c-640-480-1.jpg');background-size:cover;} **/
```

```html
<a href="#" class="btn">Hello!</a>
```

Comment: @Apolo Radomer try this

Answer (score 0):

Try this below

```css
.up {
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    border-style: inset;
    border-width: 0 100px 173.2px 100px;
    border-color: transparent transparent #007bff transparent;
    float: left;
    transform:rotate(540deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(540deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(540deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(540deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(540deg);
  display:block;
}

.up p {
    text-align: center;
    top: 59px;
    left: -47px;
    position: relative;
    width: 93px;
    height: 93px;
    margin: 0px;
     -webkit-transform:rotate(540deg);
      transform:rotate(540deg));
    -ms-transform:rotate(540deg));
    -moz-transform:rotate(540deg));
     -o-transform:rotate(540deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="up">
<p>some information text goes here</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a way to make this dynamic without using JS? For example : `border-width: 0 100% 173.2px 100%;` ? Or at least use a function that will get the actual width of the screen or the parent div? and then assign it there.

Comment: I didn't understand your words. can u explain simply and clearly for me.@ Apolo Radomer

Comment: I want to get the full width of the page. In the border width it is set to 100px. How can I change that to 100%

Comment: It possible to add 100% bt when you give 100% you need to increase the height depend on screen size

Comment: 1) I could use 100% and auto? Did not work for me. 2) Is there a chance that there are implications in a WYSIWYG widget?